# show CSS .map files in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, less, web-essentials

Is it possible to show generated css .map files in Visual Studio's solution explorer?
Something like:

```
- file.less
|
--- file.css
|
------file.css.map
```

Why, you ask? Well I want to set the build action of certain files so when a project is published it won't pollute a deployment location.

Comment: In VS2013, click on 'show on file' button ([fourth one from the right under Solution Explorer caption](http://visualstudioaddins.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/solution-explorer-errors-in-visual-studio-2013.png?w=900)), right-click and 'Include in Project'. If `.map` is already added in project, it should show in Solution Explorer. To wit; create a less file in project and compile (save or build -- depending on your WE settings). It will add `.css` file nested under  `.less` and `.css.map` file nested under `.css`.

Comment: Thanks. Can't see how I missed the nested collapsible .css file